# How to Loop through only a few elements of an array of object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How to Loop through a given array of object so as to be able to use elements in a mixed order. This is pretty simple using for Loop but given that driver.sleep(ms) is an asynchronous function it wouldn't work. How to accomplish the following using forEach?

```
var x = [
   { a: 'Quas',
     b: 'Quas',
     c: 'Quas'
   },
   { a: 'Wex',
     b: 'Wex',
     c: 'Wex'
   },
   { a: 'Exort',
     b: 'Exort',
     c: 'Exort'
   }
]   
x.forEach(function(instance) {
    var a = instance.a;
    var b = instance.b;
    var c = instance.c;
    driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
        console.log(a);
    });
    driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
        console.log(b);
    });
    driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
        console.log(c);
    });
    driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
        console.log("Invoke");
    });
});
```

Given code prints:
Quas
Quas
Quas
Quas
Invoke
Wex
Wex
Wex
Invoke
Exort
Exort
Exort
Invoke

How to loop through the array of object such that it logs:
Quas
Wex
Wex
Invoke
Quas
Wex
Exort
Invoke
Quas
Exort
Exort
Invoke

**Note that driver.sleep(ms) is asynchronous.**

Comment: @Andreas question edited to keep it correct.

Comment: `sleep` may be *asynchronous* but the calls are all made, immediately and in order, and all sleeping for the exact same duration before getting logged. How would they end up mixed?

Comment: So you want them in a mixed order or what? I'm kinda lost.

Comment: @David using for loop didn't work as `for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` causes the i to become 4 even before reaching the statements within for loop for execution. That's why I'm using forEach.

Comment: @EyuelDK Required Order is given in the question itself.

Comment: I would have appreciated an answer instead or a referral to your question. I read the question, but it left me confused. If you want them to be out-of-order purposefully then just randomly sort them and call the async methods. If I'm mistaken on your goal, please clarify.

Comment: Regardless of whether you use `for` (and mind your variable scopes) or `forEach`, the iteration will still be sequential. I never addressed your use of `forEach`, I explained why your calls will still be made in order. You need to explain the logic of what you want to achieve. If all you need is a specific different order, then maybe don't make the calls in the current order? Change the values of `a`, `b` and `c` to match your needs or simply make a single call to `console.log('Quas\nWex\nWex\nInvoke\n.......');` ?

Comment: @EyuelDK sure.. I wanted to use this exact array to achieve that order as I'm using the array elsewhere too and it would be better not to manipulate the structure of this array or create another one to achieve the goal but to write code that does it for me.

Comment: But there is no - apparent - logic to the desired order. If you want to hard-code the logging to a specific order, I'd argue it's more readable to hard-code a new object in the desired order. If you were asking for just logging all the a's, and then all the b's, instead of each key for each object, it would be trivial, but that would give `Quas-Wex-Exort`, not the desired `Quas-Wex-Wex`. If there is no *logic* to the desired order - if the only reason that's the correct order is because that's how it is in another place - then it'll have to be hard coded (or fetched from said other place).

Comment: @DavidHedlund There's no logic for getting the desired order in this question but then the question is to find out if at all it is possible to get the desired order using forEach and given array? I could create another array to get the desired order but is it possible to to get that order using the given array itself?

Comment: @PawanJuyal I think you are missing the point. We are asking you what order you seem to be talking about? If you already know the order and it is static, then just print out the expected output as it. But if you wish to compute the output there must be some logic in regards to the order of output. So here are your possible choice: "It is random", "Yes, there is a logic and here it is", "No, there is no logic and it should always print the *expected* result as shown above"... Choose.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and the order is completely arbitrary (but not random), then no, I don't see how you could use `for` or `forEach` to reproduce that order by itself. You'd have to provide it with instructions as to which order to use. You could define that as `var order = [[0,'a'],[1,'a'],[1,'b'],...];` and then iterate that: `order.forEach(function(item) { driver.sleep(2000).then(function() { console.log(x[item[0]][item[1]]); }); });` But then as I said you may as well skip the iteration and do  `console.log('Quas'); console.log('Wex'); console.log('Wex'); ...`

Comment: @EyuelDK "No, there is no logic and it should always print the expected result as shown above".

Comment: Great, here is the solution then `console.log("Quas\nWex\nWex\nInvoke\nQuas\nWex\nExort\nInvoke\nQuas\nExort\nExort\nInvoke");` If you find this solution unsatisfactory, then you probably don't understand the problem you are trying to solve. This 100% meets your specs,

Comment: @EyuelDK Yes it will give us the desired order. I agree. I need this order by usng the array. If at a later stage I wish to change the value of one of the key: value pair of an object in the array, this solution won't change the output accordingly.  Note that in given code I didn't directly put value in console.log but passed a reference to that value. Hope this makes the question a bit more clearer.

Comment: @PawanJuyal: OK, so `x[0].a` may at a later point be something else than "Quas"? But the fact that this should be the first logged item will never change? In that case, my solution with an `order` variable above will do. But it raises another question, when we just see that you want "Wex", we don't know if you mean `x[1].a` or `x[1].b` or `x[1].c`. Can we assume that the last logged "Wex" is always `c` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var x = [
   { a: 'Quas', b: 'Quas', c: 'Quas' },
   { a: 'Wex', b: 'Wex', c: 'Wex' },
   { a: 'Exort', b: 'Exort', c: 'Exort' }
];

var order = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2];
var loggedKeys = {};
order.forEach(function(i, index) {
  
  var loggingKey;
  var loggableKeys = Object.keys(x[i]).sort();
  if (loggedKeys[i] === undefined) {
    loggingKey = loggableKeys[0];
  } else {
    var k = loggableKeys.indexOf(loggedKeys[i]);
    loggingKey = loggableKeys[k + 1];
  }
  console.log(loggingKey, x[i][loggingKey]);  // Print here
  loggedKeys[i] = loggingKey;
  
  if ((index+1) % 3 == 0) {
      console.log('Invoke');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in comments, this appears to be the best you can do to address your speficic needs.

We haven't discussed what the role of "Invoke" is, so I've just thrown it in there.

Disregard the initial code section, it's just there to simulate your `driver.sleep` code. The part of the code that is the actual solution is where you specify a predefined order, and iterate over that, rather than iterating over `x` itself.

```js
// mock node
var driver = {
   sleep: function(timeout) {
      var promise = { 
         then: function(callback) {
            this.invoke = callback;
         }
      };
      setTimeout(function() { promise.invoke(); }, timeout);
      return promise;
   }
};

var x = [
   { a: 'Quas',
     b: 'Quas',
     c: 'Quas'
   },
   { a: 'Wex',
     b: 'Wex',
     c: 'Wex'
   },
   { a: 'Exort',
     b: 'Exort',
     c: 'Exort'
   }
];

var specificArbitraryOrder = [
  [0,'a'],[1,'a'],[1,'b'],'Invoke',
  [0,'b'],[1,'c'],[2,'a'],'Invoke',
  [0,'c'],[2,'b'],[2,'c'],'Invoke'
];

specificArbitraryOrder.forEach(function(item) {
    driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
        if(typeof item === 'string')
           console.log(item);
        else
           console.log(x[item[0]][item[1]]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think I figured out the "hidden" pattern. It isn't arbitrary to a certain degree. The inner keys, i.e. the object keys, are most likely called in order. If you notice the pattern, a specific array index is only printed 3 times. I assume that each print advances the output to the next key in the object. For example, for the first print of `0` index, `a` is printed out. For the second print of `0` index, `b` is printed out. TBH, this was a waste of time, but it was interested try to bridge the gap of confusion.

Comment: That's probably correct, although the only reason that alleged *pattern* exists is that you and I both have assumed that it does. That's one level of potential randomization that has been obscured by the fact that the values are identical. When OP says he wants "Wex", we don't know whether that's `a`, `b` or `c`, but we've both assumed that the first instance is `a`. My code is broken if it turns out the first "Wex" is in fact `x[1].c`, although my solution will be a lot simpler to fix. If our assumption holds true, yours is certainly more manageable if the list is extended to 1000 or so items